# Auto Populate a form from Email?

Tags: email, autocomplete

Can you have a link in an email, which takes a user to a form, and then populate the input field for 'email' with the user's email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You need to have a get parameter on the link. For example, if you have a text-box on form with the id or name parameter of "email", your link should look like this:

```
http://example.com/page.html?email=[replaceWithEmailAddress]
```

For multiple parameters:

```
http://example.com/page.html?email=[replaceWithEmailAddress]&otherId=[replaceWithValue]
```

Answer (score 1):

When preparing the email, embed the email address into the url. Therefore, it becomes part of the [GET request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GET_%28HTTP%29#Request_methods).